# Valgrind "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" Error

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

I am getting many errors with valgrind saying "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)".

Below is the one of the blocks. All of them are similar:

```
vasm_sourceline_info_t* line = asmState->firstLine;
if (line == NULL) return;
while ((line = line->next) != NULL)
{
   printf ("[%s(%i)] %s\n", line->fileName, line->lineNumber, line->data);
}
```

The error itself is on the while() line. `vasm_sourceline_info` is a doubly linked list structure. The code ~works~ but this error is worrying. Is there something else in code stomping on memory, or is the above function flawed in some way?

Comment: are all the next pointers initialized?

Comment: You know you would think that would be the FIRST thing I would look at... No, although I take care in the add/remove/append logic, the initialization function did NOT set next/prev to NULL... Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: it happens or me too in valid code sometimes.

Comment: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals

Answer (score 14):

Compile with optimizations OFF (`-O0`). Run valgrind with `--track-origins=yes` to determine the source of the errors. See [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals) for more.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with the code per se, but if one of the lines' `next` field has not been initialized (presumably the last line's `next` field), that would explain the message.